# How to improve LSTM model predictions and accuracy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

After creating pre-embedded layer using gensim my val_accuracy has gone down to 45% for 4600 records:-

```
model =  models.Sequential()
   
    model.add(Embedding(input_dim=MAX_NB_WORDS, output_dim=EMBEDDING_DIM, 
                         weights=[embedding_model],trainable=False,
                        input_length=seq_len,mask_zero=True))
    #model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.2))
       
    
    #model.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size, 64))
    model.add(GRU(units=150, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(LSTM(units=200,dropout=0.4))  
    #model.add(Dropout(0.8))
    #model.add(LSTM(100)) 
    #model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    #Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(embedding_dim))
    #model.add(LSTM(400,input_shape=(1117, 100),return_sequences=True))
    #model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128)))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    #
    #model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    #model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', 
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Model: "sequential_4"

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_4 (Embedding)      (None, 50, 100)           2746300   
_________________________________________________________________
gru_4 (GRU)                  (None, 50, 150)           112950    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 50, 150)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                (None, 200)               280800    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 100)               20100     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 404       
=================================================================
Total params: 3,160,554
Trainable params: 414,254
Non-trainable params: 2,746,300
_________________________________________________________________
```

Full code is at
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13N94kBKkHIX2TR5B_lETyuH1QTC5VuRf?usp=sharing

It would be great help for me.Since i am new in deep learning and i tried almost everything i knew.But now am all blank.

Comment: Can you expand on the problem? What kind of prediction are you getting from your model?

Comment: May be your model is overfitting. Have you checked the confusion matrix?

Comment: @AbhinavGoyal  i am passing the X as the input after tokenizing and in result my model predicts the category in which the sentence will come as in Y. You can check the code at  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CuVYRKlOoTRYwvRUGxhI7uASBGcd5Bsj?usp=sharing

Comment: @Aka Yes i have checked the matrix but since the model is giving only 30% accuracy.Matrix info is not helping me.Have a look at code https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CuVYRKlOoTRYwvRUGxhI7uASBGcd5Bsj?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your input. You've padded your input sequences with zeros but have not provided this information to your model. So your model doesn't ignore the zeros which is the reason it's not learning at all. To resolve this, change your embedding layer as follows:

```
model.add(layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size+1,
      output_dim=embedding_dim,
      mask_zero=True))
```

This will enable your model to ignore the zero padding and learn. Training with this, I got a training accuracy of 100% in just 6 epochs though validation accuracy wasn't that good (aroung 54%) which is expected as your training data contains only 32 examples. More about embedding layer: https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/embedding/

---

Since your dataset is small, the model tends to overfit on training data quite easily which gives lower validation accuracy. To mitigate this to some extent, you can try using pre-trained word embeddings like word2vec or GloVe instead of training your own embedding layer. Also, try some text data augmentation methods like creating artificial data using templates or replacing words in training data with their synonyms. You can also experiment with different types of layers (like replacing GRU with another LSTM) but in my opinion that may not help much here and should be considered after trying out pre-trained embeddings and data augmentation.

Comment: i have tried with dataset having 1988 records.Also,increased the units in layer along with some modifications, now accuracy is coming around 88%.Does anything else i can  do to improve accuracy to 95%+?

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CuVYRKlOoTRYwvRUGxhI7uASBGcd5Bsj?usp=sharing

Comment: Since your model already overfits the training data, I think increasing the number of units or hidden layers may affect the performance adversely. It helps in cases when your model underfits the data. As for how to improve validation accuracy, I've updated my answer with some ideas. Let me know if any of them helps.

Comment: I have now 3640 records. I tried both without and with  "glove.6B.50d.txt" for the embedding matrix. Also increased units in Layers and did some modification but accuracy is still coming around 80 %. There is model folder size constraint as I can't increase the size beyond 200mb. Therefore, Any suggestions which can be done without using "Glove.5d" file. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CuVYRKlOoTRYwvRUGxhI7uASBGcd5Bsj?usp=sharing .Thanks

Comment: You have to understand that machine learning is not magic. To increase your model's accuracy, you have to experiment with data, preprocessing, model and optimization techniques. And even after that, you may not get such high test accuracy because of limitations of data, computation resources or the model etc. My suggestion would be to analyze the data properly, set realistic expectations and apply techniques according to that analysis instead of just throwing the data you have at any random ML model. Anyways, all the best for further experiments :)